# Problems with SSL certificate in IIS 8

Tags: redirects, security-certificate, iis8

I bought certificate only for `name_domain.com` under the configuration for IIS 8 (on Windows Server 2012).

I have 301 redirects from `www.name_domain.com` to `https://name_domain.com`. If I open the following link in a browser: `www.name_domain.com` , there's a certificate error.

Should I buy a new certificate or maybe there is another solution to the problem?

Comment: Did you install the certificate and bind it to your site as covered [here](http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=8713)? Did you completely clear the cache in your browsers? There are online SSL check sites, as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: The certificate was installed. If we go to the website name_domain.com we have redirect to https://name_domain.com and there is no problem with certificate. The problem is when we write www.name_domian.com in the browser- then firstly it is chcecking the certificate and the next step the redirect to https://name_domain.com is made. I installed the certificate in another way than it is presented under the link you sent me. Namely, I generated a PFX file, clicked on it twice and then installed. The next steps of the IIS8 configuration were those from the points 7 and of your link.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you purchase a static single domain certificate which only covers the domain name and not subdomain.

Sadly, www. is a sub by certificate standards.

If that is the case I see 3 moves you could make.

**1.** Purchase another certificate for the www. that you never plan on using and make a redirect. (Waste of cash, forget I even mentioned it. Unless you plan on using www.name_domain.com to host content one day.

**2.** **Leave your name_domain.com as it is**, **create a new website** in your **IIS** name it **www.Redirect_domain.com**. In your **basic bindings** settings assign the common IP (SSL/Non SSL) using port 80 http: www.name_domain.com. Save it. 
In the HTTP Redirect make your permanent redirect to exact destination of name_domain.com (or relative if you are migrating for SEO reasons.)

**3.** Leave both on the one binding www.name_domain.com port 80 http and the name_domain.com on SSL port 443. 
Now you'll have to work with a local redirect from any.name_domain.com to name_domain.com this can be done with your web.config.

My personal experience (The second option is best 2) is to take a few minutes and create a new IIS website for the www.name_domain.com and do the redirect to the https://name_domain.com
But this is only true if you're planning on 301 redirects from www.name_domain.com.

Your settings my be SSL "All Unassigned" if you have any issues with routing in your IIS bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure a different virtual host for you `www` version of the domain using [these instructions](http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a194/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services.aspx).  When the certificate is handled by a separated virtual host than the www removal redirect, it should check the certificate when redirecting.